Were my actions over a takeout double correct under either actual or different circumstances?
At matchpoints, my left hand opponent opened one diamond. Partner doubled (takeout). Right hand opponent stuck in a one heart bid, which theoretically "took me off the hook."
I elected to bid one spade with ♠QTxxx ♥JT ♦Jx ♣Txxx. This was now a "free" bid, which usually entails eight points (partner had expected 10). Factors in my decision to bid light included the fifth spade, three tens, and two doubletons in the opponents' suits, which would make "transportation" easy, despite my low point count.
Partner raised me directly to four spades with an 18 count consisting of  ♠AKJ ♥AKxx ♦xxx ♣QJx, leading to a result of down two. In partner's shoes, I would raised to only three spades , holding only three spades. According to these tables of data an eight card fit with a 18-4 high card point distribution is a decided favorite to make nine tricks, while a nine card fit is slightly favored to make 10 tricks.
Given that we were vulnerable, our down two led to a "shared" bottom (with others). I would think twice about doing this again when vulnerable. But if we were not not vulnerable, or partner had bid only three spades, -100 would have gotten us a shared top against opposing part scores.
So was vulnerability the deciding factor in how I should have responded, or were other considerations?

I agree with the answerers that nowadays your 1S call does not promise 8 points or so. I would bid 1S with your cards, but if your partner expects more, then you must pass. But I really don't like the 4S bid. The opponents have not found a fit, so the "promised" diamond shortage they don't have is a big minus. 4333s generally play badly.

This depends on your agreements with your partner.
If you've agreed with partner that your 1S bid promises 8 points, then you have nowhere near it and shouldn't bid.
Now, even if your 1S bid does promise strength, I don't like partner's 4S bid, or a 3S bid, because you haven't promised 5 spades for your bid.  I much prefer 2D, artificial and forcing (promising at least around the kind of strength your partner has), giving you a chance to bid something other than spades if you only have 4.
Personally, I prefer to agree that a free bid, especially at the 1 level, doesn't promise very much strength, just enough distribution to encourage partner to compete further, even if they have a minimum.  Since -100 is better than -110 and disrupting their bidding can have good effects even if they have game (or make it harder for them to find their slam), I think it's worth bidding 1S on almost all hands with 5 spades.  (Almost: I wouldn't even think about bidding with xxxxx QJx xxx xx.)  Think of it this way - even if your partner has the flattest almost minimum like KJx AQx xxx Kxxx, wouldn't you want to be playing 2S rather than letting the opponents play 2H?  The opponents are quite unlikely to double.  (And if your partner has an even weaker hand, it won't cost to try 2S at some point, because opponents have a game and 2SX is unlikely to be down 3.)
But if your partner isn't willing to play this, your choices are to pass and accept a bad score when your partnership should have competed, to bid and accept a bad score (and maybe an angry partner) when your partner bids expecting you to have something, or to find a new partner.  (For serious games, I would go the find a new partner route; for less serious games, I would do what partner prefers, keeping in mind some weaker partners do want me to mastermind and hand hog.)

I am in a "social" bridge club where people are assigned parts (unless they sign up for games as a pair). "Rejecting" a partner assignment is saved for the very worst cases, like when a partner yells at you repeatedly.

In that case, the right thing to do is always whatever your partner wants, not whatever is the best bridge action.

Also - if you're actually interested in learning how to play good bridge, you need a better game.

I'd argue that I have "stretchy" eight points, though not 8 HCPS. I count 4 HCPS, a fifth point for my three tens, two points for the fifth spade (partner only has the right to expect four) and one point for the doubleton in diamonds. The club standard is "eight," and while I'm rounding up, I am doing so within normal club limits. I hadn't realized that my (occasional) partner is ultra conservative, even by club standards.

I am absolutely of the opinion that the best partnership agreement is to allow a 1S bid with Qxxxx x xxx xxxx (unless you want to agree that jump bids are weak after responder bids, in which case you have a 2S bid).  Your Jx and JT aren't worth more than xx and xx here.  Being able to get to -100 rather than -110 is important; it's a frequent source of matchpoints.  But - as I have said - if your partner doesn't agree that -100 is better than -110, you don't have any good options.

As usual, agreeing with everything @AlexanderWoo says.  I'd probably be using 2♥ as the force rather than 2♦ but that's more likely to be useful exposing a psychic, so he's probably right.  Not that anybody's psyched this auction outside absolute flight A in 15 years...
My "rule #1": if I choose to bend or violate system, I own the result.  Even if partner should have figured it out, if they don't, it's my fault if it's wrong.  Of course, if it was right, I get to own at least 50% of the good score!
You chose to violate system, for good reason (I think this agreement is silly.  "Free bids showing strength" have mostly gone the way of the dodo, for very very good reasons involving "winning the partscore", "finding our fit", and "finding the right lead against their contract".  Of course, pass meaning "I have nothing interesting to say" or "feel free to describe your hand further" in many of these "free bid" auctions is often the best call; but if you do have something interesting to say, say it.  And telling partner your side has a fit in the boss suit is "something interesting".)  Partner made a call that wasn't best, based partly on not knowing how to investigate, and partly on "knowing you have stuff" (where he thought the 1♥ bidder's points were, given he can count 12+18+10 in the other three hands, is a question.  But if you "know" partner has to have it, it is difficult to think past that "knowledge" to "that's impossible").
There is fault going to partner for their handling of this hand; but the bad result is yours to own; you don't have what partner expected.
You have two (well, three) choices. You can suck it up and bid partner's style, and eat all the bad results you get from passing where others are finding their fits, or you can take flyers and own the results, good or bad.
Or you can have discussions with your partners and try to convince them their bidding style is (deservedly) old-fashioned, and join the 21st century.  Which will also lead to poor results as they learn how, even if they agree to try; but eventually better.

Its easier looking at things with hindsight, but i’d say you were both bidding very optimistically, whether vulnerable or not.
First, your 4 points includes two worthless jack doubletons and no singletons, looks worth more like 2-3 points although good enough for a 2nd round bid, while partners horribly flat 18 points 3 spade hand is more like 16 and not really worth a rebid.
I think your Partner is more defensive and shouldn't really get above 2S. Let opponents bid 3D, partner should leave them there and you will probably get them down 1 (using law of total tricks) for the best positive score. If they stopped in 1NT then leave them there, you’re laughing with 7 defensive tricks off the top (what does double dummy show is best achievable?!)
I’d estimate optimum bidding as 1D X 1H P 2D P P 2S P3D (all pass).
Partners defensive hand on lead looks worth HAK, AS, and couple more trick somewhere from a 2nd spade, a club, or a heart ruff or perhaps trump promotion.
But even 3D making is cheaper than 3Sx-1 vulnerable. Dont feel bad when you get low score because other pairs weren’t good enough to penalise their opponents properly.

I'll grant you that the jack of diamonds is probably worthless, but no the JT of hearts. With the takeout double, partner has promised Qss or better in hearts, and JT plays well opposite such a holding; I'd argue that the JT sequence in hearts is worth two points.

@TomAu. The JT might have some value in defense but none in offense (as is generally the case for side suits lead by quacks). So, all the more reason to defend. In offence, you could only ruff your hearts with long trumps which were already winners.

If I wanted to reach 3S when not vulnerable, i’d jump  to 3S after passing on my first bid. Although i prefer my chance of a + score by defending this hand.
